# Use EventEmitter with NodeJs and Azure Functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure-functions, eventemitter

Is it possible to use event emitters in NodeJS / Typescript for Azure Functions given the Serverless nature of Azure Functions? For high throughput scenarios, perhaps millions of requests per day to a single Azure function endpoint, I want to make sure that I don't end up with orphaned events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leverage [Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview), the distributed cousin of the in-memory `EventEmitter` for your scenario.

Here is how you can compare these

- Instead of an `EventEmitter` object, you will have an [Event Grid Topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-topics)
- Instead of a listener, you will have an [Event Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-handlers)
- Instead of `.emit()`, you [`POST` to the custom topic's endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/post-to-custom-topic)
- Instead of `.on()`, you use [Event Filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering)

As for scale, Event Grid has you covered as it was designed for such use cases.

Also, Event Grid has [retry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#retry-schedule-and-duration) built-in and supports [dead-lettering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#dead-letter-events) as well.